# Shrink margins on resize

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How do I make the content take up the margin space when the browser is resized smaller?

http://jsfiddle.net/denWG/62/

Html:

```
<div class="jp-sleek jp-jplayer jp-audio">
  <div class="jp-gui">
    <div class="jp-controls jp-icon-controls">
      <div class="jp-progress">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.jp-jplayer {
    min-width: 900px;
}

.jp-sleek .jp-gui {
    height: 42px;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    position: relative;
}

.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-controls {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;
}

.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-icon-controls .jp-progress {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100%;
    width: 600px;
    min-width: 240px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Here's what it does at the moment:
[image]

I want the margins on the left and right to shrink down and for the green bar to get bigger and take up more margin space until it's 100% as the screen size gets smaller.

Comment: is it what you need?: http://jsfiddle.net/banzay52/0jmpss99/

Comment: @Banzay that's what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `width: 100%;` to `.jp-jplayer` and `min-width: 450px` to `.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-controls`:

```css
.jp-jplayer {
    width: 100%;
}

.jp-sleek .jp-gui {
    height: 42px;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    position: relative;
}

.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-controls {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;
    min-width: 450px;
}

.jp-sleek .jp-gui .jp-icon-controls .jp-progress {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100%;
    width: 600px;
    min-width: 240px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="jp-sleek jp-jplayer jp-audio">
  <div class="jp-gui">
    <div class="jp-controls jp-icon-controls">
      <div class="jp-progress">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```